# AS3 Parallax Scrolling Blinking some Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi i am new to actionscript 3 Games development i am using Continue Background of a 31 x 500 Pixels height and width repsectively of image
But the prob. is when i try to run my SWF file the moving objects Blink 2 times i don't know why its happening here is the code:
if anybody wants demo of swf file i will upload it somewhere and give it

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var br:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
 var br1:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
 br=new Branch();
br1=new Branch();
 br1.x=br.width;
addChild(br);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveScroll); 
function moveScroll(e:Event):void{
br.x -= 10;  
br1.x -= 10;  

if(br.x < -br.width){
br.x = br.width;
}else if(br1.x < -br1.width){
br1.x = br1.width;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the br var twice.  Do this instead (assuming Branch is a library object):

```
var br:Branch = new Branch();
var br1:Branch = new Branch();
```

Comment: i tried but it's again blinking it's just a sample of my code i have a full Game going on and i got stuck at this :(

Comment: or you can say the background is not smooth i think it's because framerate or any other issue

Comment: http://2947.a.hostable.me/pappu-pakia.swf Here is the swf file when you hit play it will show you a branch and the blinking porton
and here is the code
`branchContainer.x = (63 - pappu.x)*0.03;`
`branch.height=toRandom(200,800);`
`branch3.height=1000-branch.height;`
`branch3.y=branch.height+150;`   `
`if (branch.x + 1000 + branchContainer.x < 0)`
`{`
`branch.x = branch.x + (2 * 1000);`
`}`
`if (branch3.x + 1000 + branchContainer.x < 0)`
`{`
`branch3.x = branch3.x + (2 * 1000);`
`}`

Comment: I don't see any blinking - I hit start and the two branches appear and the bird drops to the ground

Comment: no no hit any key and it will start flying then the branch will come and background will move then you will see the blink & also thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I see it now - it's not blinking, you're scaling/changing the size of the branches every frame.  Comment out that code and just leave the changes to the x position.  Don't change the height, width or y values and you might see a change for the better.

Comment: oh so it's happening because of height but when i comment the code the blinking part is not happening instead of this what is now happening is i can see it change on every frame i think that is frame per / Second issue

Thanks for the help :)